# Have two copies of windows 10 on one PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, license

Currently, I have Windows 10 running on my PC with an SSD drive. I bought a new HDD and connected it to my computer.

I want to install Windows 10 on my HDD so that I can boot from either one. I know how to install it on the second (using an ISO), but what will happen with the license? I will be running two copies of windows, but only on one PC.

Comment: What you describe technically is in violation of the license.

Comment: You will need 2 licenses to do that legally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technical Aspects:** 
I believe most Windows 10 license's now (especially if you upgraded from an earlier version of windows) are hardware-locked and will re-activate automatically in the case that you wipe your drive and re-install it. For this reason, it should in theory be possible to install another copy of Windows 10 to your secondary hard drive and have it activate automatically using your existing license.

**Concerns:** 
All of that said, just because you ***can*** doesn't mean you ***should***.  Its almost certainly in violation of Microsofts license policy. The fact is, you may not get caught, and it may not be a big deal - but there is the possibility that both operating systems will continue to report back to Microsoft, and will continually report different storage disk serial numbers which might look suspicious after a time.

I'd recommend that if you're adamant on doing this that you purchase a second, stand-alone license to use on your secondary hard drive, or just re-think the reasons that you want to do this in the first place.